# Safety delete ea-php56 content files

Tags: php, centos

I have a CRITICAL issue with the Inodes of my server.

This is the `df -i` result:

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/simfs     9830400 9830400      0  100% /
none            524288     178 524110    1% /dev
tmpfs            10240       1  10239    1% /tmp/mysqltmp
```

So, after several investigation in my drive I found that the folder with issues is this:

```
for i in /var/cpanel/php/sessions/*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```

This is the result:

```
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php54
1
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php55
1
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56
9100235
```

So, obviously there is the issue.
My question is, Can I delete te files inside that folder?

I know that maybe the users lost their session data but, just login again and done.

Comment: Those are just temporary session file serializations. Go ahead. -- Also, a cron job.

Comment: Yes, but seems that the cPanel support does't know this and telling me that can't delete those files because are "system files" LOL.

Comment: Use SSH not a LOL frontend.

Comment: The Putty just crash, I do a rm -rf in that folder, maybe is too many files

Comment: rm -rf /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56/* and just crash

Comment: Solved! ls -1 -f | xargs rm -rfv